# Show hide content based on check boxes, if one check box checked disable another check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three check boxes, first one will be checked by default and content will display, corresponding to first check box.

if I checked second checked box, first check box will unchecked and content will change, corresponding to second check box.

If I checked third checkbox, rest of the check boxes will unchecked and content will change, corresponding to third check box.

Below is the my code, but some how its not working

```
    <fieldset class="question">
           <label for="coupon_question">Show India content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="question">
           <label for="coupon_question">Show Japan content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="question">
           <label for="coupon_question">Show China content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="answer">
           <label for="coupon_field">India Content:</label>
           <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field"/>
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="answer">
           <label for="coupon_field">Japan Content:</label>
           <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field"/>
       </fieldset>


       <fieldset class="answer">
           <label for="coupon_field">China Content:</label>
           <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field"/>
       </fieldset>

Below is my jquery

<script>
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(".coupon_question").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".answer").show();
        } else {
            $(".answer").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that It's should always be unique `coupon_field`

Comment: can you some sample code to me

Answer (score 1):

1 way you can solve it is by getting the index of the checkbox, and use that to determent what answer shall be shown.

```
$(".answer").hide();
$(".coupon_question").click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index(".coupon_question");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".answer").eq(i).show();
  } else {
    $(".answer").eq(i).hide();
  }
});
```

**Demo with checkbox**

```js
$(".answer").hide();
$(".coupon_question").click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index(".coupon_question");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".answer").eq(i).show();
  } else {
    $(".answer").eq(i).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show India content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show Japan content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show China content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">India Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">Japan Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">China Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>
```

**Demo with radio**

```js
$(".answer").hide();
$(".coupon_question").click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index(".coupon_question");
  $(".answer").hide();
  $(".answer").eq(i).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show India content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="radio" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show Japan content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="radio" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Show China content</label><input class="coupon_question" type="radio" name="coupon_question" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">India Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">Japan Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">China Content:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: but when first check box content will display, rest of the check box should unchecked, and another checkbox content should hide, at time one check box will checked and one content should display, please help

Comment: @kunal If you only want 1 checkbox to be active at the time, why not use radio buttons?

Comment: yes we can use radio button, but at a time one radio button content should display, please provide some sample code, really it will help for me

Comment: @kunal did you look at my second demo`?